# What's the difference between wave equation in PDE form and wave equation in normal form?

Tags: terminology, ordinary-differential-equations

What's the difference between "wave equation in partial derivative form" and "wave equation in y(x,t) form" ? Are they both same? And why "wave equation in in y(x,t) form" is the solution of "wave equation in partial derivative form" ?

[image]

Comment: What? Are you asking why the sine is a solution to the wave equation? Just plug it in!

Comment: See my comment below.

Comment: Some vocabulary that is often skimmed over in introductory treatments and generally forgotten by students the first anyway. A wave is a traveling disturbance. *Any* traveling disturbance. A wave the repeats is "periodic". A wave that sinusoidal in form is "harmonic". Not all waves are periodic, nor are all waves harmonic.

Comment: Note that $ y(x, t) $ is not an "equation", it's a *function*.  If somebody gives you a function $ y (x, t) $, you can check whether or not that function is a solution of the wave equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The* (1D) [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) is
$$ \frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2} = v^2 \frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}, $$
where for simplicity let's just assume $v$ is a constant independent of time $t$ or space $x$. This is a differential equation describing a function $y$ of $t$ and $x$.

*A* solution to the wave equation is *any* expression $y(x,t)$ such that differentiating $y$ and plugging it into the wave equation yields something true. For example, $y(x,t) = xt^2$ is *not* a solution, since we have $\partial^2y/\partial t^2 = 2x$ and $\partial^2y/\partial x^2 = 0$, and
$$ 2x \neq v^2 \cdot 0 $$
(at least they are not equal *everywhere*).

As it turns out, though, *any* suitably differentiable function of $x-vt$ *is* a solution. That is, if $y(x,t) = f(x-vt)$, then
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} y(x,t) = v^2 f''(x-vt) = v^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} y(x,t). $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I have few questions - If any equation y(x,t) is a solution of the wave equation, it means that y(x,t) is a some kind of a wave or sinusoidal wave? And PDE(1D) wave equation represents a sinusoidal wave or any kind of wave ? And what's the significance of PDE(1D) wave equation?

Comment: People are often interested in sinusoidal solutions, but there are others. In general a solution is something that keeps its shape while moving at velocity $v$. And the wave equation describes many, many phenomena in physics.

Comment: In adidition to what @ChrisWhite said, any solution of the wave equation can be written as a sum of sinusoidal waves.

Comment: "in general a solution is something that keeps its shape while moving at velocity $v$". If $v$ is a function of wavenumber $k$ (or frequency, or wavelength... pick your variable) then this is no longer true. But it is true if $v$ is constant.

Comment: @Floris $v$ is supposed to be a constant in the wave equation.

Comment: @Dylan putting v as a constant is convenient but not necessary I thought. Either way it is an expression describing the spatiotemporal evolution of a disturbance.